# What should I do if my question is closed for "Exact duplicate"?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

What if my question is not a exact duplicate, but people vote to close it without reading?

Should I answer the pointed duplicate question with my question or what?

It has 3 reopen votes, but what if it doesn't get reopened? Should I give up and ask in somewhere else?

Comment: If you want to publicly appeal to Meta about specific posts, it helps to link to it. Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102806/how-should-i-concatenate-strings-closed?

Comment: Yes, exactly !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something of substantive note here is that when you know there's a very similar question to yours that *might* be mis-interpreted as an exact (or in this case close) duplicate you should consider highlighting that you've in fact read that question and its answers, and determined for reasons that you then list that your question is in fact unique, different, or requires solutions the other question could never generate.

In particular, you're demonstrating a fundamental question asking skill by doing this -- posing a question with your own research and really illustrating your interest and desire to find an answer.

Ideally, linking to the similar-but-different question provides a meaningful reference for what answers you're *not* interested in and helps further clarify your question.  Additionally, the cross-linking might help someone who mistakenly stumbles upon your question looking for the other one.

FWIW, I do think your question stands on its own merits, has terrific answers, and voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks for the vote and thanks for the hints, now I won't forget to mention similar questions anymore. :)