# STOP CLOSING legitimate questions. Should closing questions be made harder?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Raise the reputation required to close, raise the number of votes needed to close, allow "anti-close" votes to keep questions OPEN, do not let someone answer AND at the same time vote to close (or at least force the answer to be community wiki so they can't whore points by reducing answer competition), etc.

Some or all of the above need to be implemented to prevent abuse of the system. It does the community NO good to close questions that are duplicate (yet perhaps the duplicates were old/outdated, or had poor answers, things change fast in IT!), questions that are not "coding" related but nevertheless important topics for developers, or even questions that are somewhat subjective yet developer-related. (Why have a voting system if every answer is black and white true or false???)

I'd like to know why some are so fast to close a question (killing sometimes very good and informative topics) and whether they actually think they are doing everyone else some kind of "favor" by doing so. I don't think the intent of Stackoverflow was to answer plain right/wrong homework coding questions. There are a lot of experienced pros here and like others I want to hear their OPINIONS on certain topics as well as receiving factual answers.

Comment: So, are you hacking? :)

Comment: @studiohack "crusader is crusading" .. at least by being recursive it could cause a stack overflow ;)

Comment: Oh.. no..... the nerd concentration here is going to create a virtual quantum singularity or something...!

Comment: @Crusader, please provide examples.

Comment: Please upvote this [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close) to be able to cast open/close votes simultaneously.

Comment: The "nerd concentration" comment is not going to help your reception any. You don't open negotiations for a favor by insult the person you're asking for help. Likewise the capitals: screaming at people only makes them more likely to help you when you have power over them, and even then it makes you unpopular.

Comment: You should include some examples. Without examples this qualifies as a general complaint and could be true or not true or unknown (Hey guys! I guess the nerd concentration just went over 9000!)

Comment: Voted to close.  It's not a real question without examples.

Comment: There are way too many duplicates on SO that never get closed. I think closing should be made easier.

Comment: lol I loled at the irony. Sorry for being so immature.

Comment: Ok although at first it was funny that a 'not closing' suggestion was closed I read it and it makes sense in the way that sometimes good questions are closed (has happened to me), and I DO feel bullied. Also, I was apologizing for my immaturity, but man, the comments above mine are a lot more immature and childish. Anyway, closing dup questions, I completely agree with that. Closing development related / non code related questions is not right.

Comment: The 'nerd concentration' comment was not an attack, I'm in the category too, I just thought the jokes were funny. @Carlo agreed, there's too much drama around here and not enough letting people ask the legitimate questions they need answers to.

Comment: @Mark C [Its over 9000!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5Gp8n5smFU)

Comment: I do not understand the culture here on Stack Overflow. So much rudeness and negativity. Why all the downvotes, criticism, and closing the thread after less than 24 hours? Kind of makes @Crusader's point for him.

Comment: Not sure how I ended up back here as I've basically stopped using this site for all practical purposes. Admittedly this Q was partly a rant out of frustration at a younger and more argumentative time. :) It is a little funny that the closing statement above is kind of the problem: "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" - so what? If it does, GOOD! These things were useful and popular, and years ago there used to be some great discussions on SO. So what if it doesn't "fit the format" well. It's still clearly informative for hundreds of people.

Comment: And no, I won't provide examples. If you've been visiting this site for any amount of time surely you'd have run into cases where a "bad" closed question has hundreds of upvotes and thousands of views. Anyone denying that isn't being honest. The infamous polling questions (which also help us find tools, they aren't just a popularity contest) particularly ended like this. But also some very educational "debate" style posts have been similarly excommunicated. SO makes me imagine a bunch of "Internet janitors", hopelessly trying to clean up something can't be cleaned, and few even care if it is.

Comment: Regarding closing duplicates... no, don't close those either. What good does it do? But the big problem there is that frequently you'll have Q's closed as duplicate incorrectly. If there isn't some very subtle difference that only an expert in a particular field would pick up on, there's also the problem that things change over time. Closing such questions prevents those legitimate issues from being addressed. On the other hand, what's the upside of closing a legitimate duplicate? The only reason I can think of is that it suppresses new user competition against people with high point counts.

Answer (score 11):

Links! Or it didn't happen.

And I'm serious, we do occasionally close a question we shouldn't, and we would like to correct those cases.

On the other hand, *I* think there are more question that *should* be closed that survive the gauntlet than there are that should remain open and get closed. I have high hope that the existence of [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) will help.

Comment: +1 you're totally right, -1 this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @Pop I started to write it as a comment, but then I though *"rant or not, there is a legitimate complaint in there somewhere"*, and the second line is my answer to it: show us a mistake and we'll fix it. 'Course, I suspect the OP just thinks he should get to use the site however he wants, in which case he'll be disappointed by the results. *C'est la vie.*

Answer (score 8):

I ran into that problem of exact duplicate once. To avoid this, you should link the `duplicated` questions and tell why they don't solve your problem.

[I got a nice answer here of what I should do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54779/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-is-closed-for-exact-duplicate).

> Something of substantive note here is
>   that when you know there's a very
>   similar question to yours that might 
>   be mis-interpreted as an exact (or in
>   this case close) duplicate you should
>   consider highlighting that you've in
>   fact read that question and its
>   answers, and determined for reasons
>   that you then list that your question
>   is in fact unique, different, or
>   requires solutions the other question
>   could never generate.
>
> In particular, you're demonstrating a
>   fundamental question asking skill by
>   doing this -- posing a question with
>   your own research and really
>   illustrating your interest and desire
>   to find an answer.
>
> Ideally, linking to the
>   similar-but-different question
>   provides a meaningful reference for
>   what answers you're not interested in
>   and helps further clarify your
>   question. Additionally, the
>   cross-linking might help someone who
>   mistakenly stumbles upon your question
>   looking for the other one.
>
> FWIW, I do think your question stands
>   on its own merits, has terrific
>   answers, and voted to reopen.