# How can I denote my question is not an exact duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836324/how-to-cheaply-assign-c-style-array-to-stdvector) which was closed as exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733143/converting-between-c-stdvector-and-c-array-without-copying). I don't agree with it, because the answers for that question don't contain the information I need. **It is in comments** and there is an [interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836324/how-to-cheaply-assign-c-style-array-to-stdvector/5837571#5837571) with allocators, which can probably be correct.

How can I say this to those who have closed my question?

I read this question 
[What should I do if my question is closed for “Exact duplicate” ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54779/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-is-closed-for-exact-duplicate)
but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: *I don't agree with it, because the answers for that question don't contain the information I need.* — whether or not *the answers* are satisfying has little to do with *a question* being a duplicate?

Comment: You seem to have a lot of problems with things not answering your question that *seem* like they should answer your question. This leads me to speculate the problem is in how you phrase your questions (and causing other people not to understand what the answer you're looking for is), rather than with the people who are answering the original question.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I don't understand your first sentence. You say I ask questions incorrectly, can you point me out what are these questions and how should I rephrase them?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. They look like duplicates to me, they *should* answer your question. You're the one who says they don't answer your question. The challenge is figuring out why not, and then correcting it.

Comment: @Arjan: I actually do consider whether the duplicate question has satisfactory answers before I close as duplicate. There's not much point in referring someone to a duplicate if it doesn't answer their question.

Comment: @DIMEDROLL: 61 people have read this question, but there's only one reopen vote on your linked question (which I assume is your vote).  I think it's pretty safe to say your question is, in fact, an actual duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is a *specific* point that you want to know and was not covered by the answers to either question (closed or not, you had five answers), then write a new question asking *that specific issue*. The global question has been answered. To reduce the chance of having the community believe it's a duplicate, **reference those two questions** and, more importantly, **explain why it's a different question**, i.e., emphasize on what is not explicit in the previous questions.

If, on the other hand, you want to know exactly what has been asked before, but the answers to not seem enough nor correct to you, add a comment to the original question and/or answers explaining why you believe those answers are not correct. You can also consider adding a bounty to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your question, and make it more specific.
if you have asked your question in general terms, but you wanted to know the answer for a specific case, then that could help. If you have a problem, but you asked about what you think is the solution, then change the question to ask about the problem you are having, and not how to implement what you think is the (better) solution.

Doing so doesn't automatically re-open your question; if the question is a duplicate of another one (which includes also the case the answer to another question is the answer for your question too), the question will not be re-open.
In the case the answer for your problem is included in a comment for an answer, I think your question is still considered a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, but I don't agree with you in that the answer can be in comments. This forces readers to read every comment to find the answer.

Comment: @DIMEDROLL Comments are still part of the answer. If who wrote the comment is the same user who wrote the answer, you can kindly ask him to write that in the answer.

Comment: @DIMEDROLL kiamlaluno is right: the comments are part of the system. If you are interested in learning, I would suggest you to read them; you will find very valuable comments quite often. Anyhow, if you found that the complete answer is scattered in several comments to different answers, you can always compile all that information in a new answer. Be kind and reference who wrote the original comment.

Answer (score 3):

I am one of those voting to close.

You asked if there is an easy way to convert between a std::vector and a C style array, without copying the elements. The answer is that there is not!

The other question might be if you can convert the other way around, but the answer is the same - you cannot! And for exactly the same reason.

That's why the question is **close enough** to be considered a duplicate.

"Can you convert A to B?". No.
"Can you convert B to A?". No.
Same reason.